# JFrame Picture in NetBeans as Background

Tags: netbeans

I'm done coding my program but I'm having a difficult time adding a picture to a JFrame (I've done everything in code without using the graphic interface JPanel.

At the moment I'm trying something like this, but it keeps giving me errors and wont display the picture. (JavaOskarTid is my package, hourglassone.jpeg my intended picture)

Thank you very much for any response!

URL urlToImage = this.getClass().getResource("JavaOskarTid/hourglassone.jpeg");
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(urlToImage);

Comment: What are the errors? Can you post more of your code? (An [sccee](http://sscce.org/))

Comment: No real error, I'm kind of ashamed to admit that I don't really know how to add the image in my JFrame, I'd greatly appreciate some input :)